# Magento 2 product error

Tags: magento2, products

When i do a google search for our products and click the link redirects to /search/

instead of the actual product.

Some are working and some are not. I would appreciate some help on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Did you changed URL? Check your url_rewrite table with the following query

```
SELECT * FROM `url_rewrite` where entity_id = [PRODUCTID] and entity_type = "product"
```

Answer (score 0):

Recommended way is clean the Urls of all products from the table **url_rewrite**.

SO first step is go to Database, search table **url_rewrite** and then truncate.

> then install module -
>   https://github.com/elgentos/regenerate-catalog-urls

Then Enable module, after run all commands:

```
php bin/magento s:up && php bin/magento s:d:c && php bin/magento s:s:d -f && php bin/magento c:c && php bin/magento c:f
```

Then: Regenerate url for all products and the global store

```
php bin/magento regenerate:product
```

Hope this will help You!!